# Implementing parameterized factory with Guice

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

I have a factory I like to reimplement using Guice:

```
enum MyObjects { OBJECT1, OBJECT2, ... }
class Object1 implements SomeInterface { ... }
class Object2 implements SomeInterface { ... }
...
class Factory {
  public static SomeInterface createObject(MyObjects obj) {
    switch (obj) {
    case OBJECT1: return new Object1();
    case OBJECT2: return new Object2();
    ...
    }
  }
```

Is there an easy way to implement it? 
Something like Provider.get(parameter) and using bindings to define which object should be used in each case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options here.

**1.** since you use an `enum` to distinguish between implementations, then you have a finite number of implementations that you can define each with their own binding, provided you use an annotation during injection

```
public @interface SomeInterfaceKind {
    MyObjects value();
}
```

in your `Module`:

```
bind(SomeInterface.class)
    .annotatedWith(new SomeInterfaceKindImpl(MyObjects1.OBJECT1)
    .to(Object1.class);
...
```

Then in classes to be injected:

```
@Inject void setSomeInterface(
    @SomeInterfaceKind(MyObjects.OBJECT1) SomeInterface object) {...}
```

Here you have to define `SomeInterfaceKindImpl` class that implements `SomeInterfaceKind` (yes, it's possible to extend an annotation!) For more details, take a look at how `Named` is implemented in Guice.

**2.** You can also use Guice **MapBinder** as follows (I find it simpler to implement)

In your Module:

```
MapBinder.newMapBinder(MyObjects.class, SomeInterface.class)
    .addBinding(MyObjects.OBJECT1).to(Object1.class);
MapBinder.newMapBinder(MyObjects.class, SomeInterface.class)
    .addBinding(MyObjects.OBJECT2).to(Object2.class);
```

Then in injected methods:

```
@Inject void setSomeInterface(Map<MyObjects, SomeInterface> map) {
    SomeInterface object1 = map.get(MyObjects.OBJECT1);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. 
As I understand the first option is more appropriate when at compile time the actual class is known, while the second option allows decision at run-time which implementation to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use assisted inject

```
public interface Factory {

    public Object1 createObject1(String param1);
    public Object2 createObject2(Date param2);

}


public class Object1 {
     @AssistedInject
     public Object1(String param1) {
          // do something
     }
}

public class Object2 {
     @AssistedInject
     public Object2(Dateparam2) {
         // do something
     }
}
```

Then in your module

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(Object1.class, Object1.class)
     .implement(Object2.class, Object2.class)
     .build(Factory.class));
```

Then you can use the factory wherever you need it

```
@Inject
private Factory factory;
```